# Finding the set of values for which a line does not intersect a curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the set of values of $k$ for which the line $y = k(4x - 3)$ does not intersect the curve $y = 4x^2 + 8x - 8$

I am trying to solve it like this

$k(4x - 3) = 4x^2 + 8x - 8 \Rightarrow 4x^2 -k(4x-3) + 8x - 8$

and then $b^2 - 4ac < 0$

but i am not able to solve it

Comment: It is $b^2-4ac$, not $b-4ac$.

Comment: You’re close. You have $$4x^2+(8-4k)x +(3k-8)=0$$ so that you want $$(8-4k)^2-4\cdot 4(3k-8) <0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(8-4k)^2-4\cdot 4(3k-8) <0.$$ $$\Longrightarrow 4^2((2-k)^2-(3k-8))<0$$ $$\Longrightarrow (k-4)(k-3)<0$$ $$ \Longrightarrow 3<k<4$$